# PortAudio: Pa_StartStream() crashes Game Maker when used in DLL

Tags: c++, dll, stream, portaudio, game-maker

I want to use PortAudio in Game Maker by using a DLL.
I made the callback function in C++ and used that to calculate the frequency of the incoming sample stream. In the DLL I made a few export functions: one that initiates the stream, one that closes the stream and one that gets the frequency variable generated by the callback.
Now when I called the PortAudioStart() function in Game Maker, the game shut down without any warning/error/message of any kind. I put MessageBox()'es in between the lines of code, to check what was the source of the crash. It showed the first, second and third ones, and then it crashed, not even showing the error MessageBox. So it turned out that Pa_StartStream() caused it.

Now I wonder: why does this crash occur, and how can I fix it?
Note: I tested this DLL by letting a C++ program call it, and in that case it worked totally as planned.

I am using GM8.0 and NetBeans 7.3 with the gcc compiler from Cygwin 4.

The start and end functions (leaving out all includes and definitions of global variables):

```
#define GMEXPORT extern "C" __declspec (dllexport)

GMEXPORT double __cdecl PortAudioStart() {
  err = Pa_Initialize();
  if( err != paNoError ) goto error;
  MessageBoxA(NULL, "1", "PortAudio DLL", MB_ICONINFORMATION);

  inputParameters.device = Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice(); /* default input device */
  if (inputParameters.device == paNoDevice) {
    goto error;
  }
  inputParameters.channelCount = 1;       /* mono input */
  inputParameters.sampleFormat = PA_SAMPLE_TYPE;
  inputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo( inputParameters.device )->defaultLowInputLatency;
  inputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;
  MessageBoxA(NULL, "2", "PortAudio DLL", MB_ICONINFORMATION);

  err = Pa_OpenStream(
            &stream,
            &inputParameters,
            NULL,                //&outputParameters
            SAMPLE_RATE,
            FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
            0,
            PaCallback,
            NULL );
  if( err != paNoError ) goto error;
  MessageBoxA(NULL, "3", "PortAudio DLL", MB_ICONINFORMATION);

  err = Pa_StartStream( stream );
  if( err != paNoError ) goto error;
  MessageBoxA(NULL, "4", "PortAudio DLL", MB_ICONINFORMATION);

  return 1;

error:
  MessageBoxA(NULL, "Apparently it doesn't work!", "PortAudio DLL", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
  Pa_Terminate();
  return 0;
}


GMEXPORT double __cdecl PortAudioEnd() {
  err = Pa_CloseStream( stream );
  if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

  Pa_Terminate();
  return 1;

error:
  MessageBoxA(NULL, "Apparently it doesn't work!", "PortAudio DLL", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
  Pa_Terminate();
  return 0;
}

GMEXPORT double __cdecl getFreq()
{
  if (Pa_IsStreamStopped(stream) == 0)
  {
    return frequency; // this variable is constantly changed in the callback function
  }
  else
  {
    return 0;
  }
}

void calculateFreq(bool sign)
{
  unsigned int j;
  bool check;
  diffsamp = maxsamp - minsamp;
  if (!sign)
  {
    diffsampmax = max((diffsampmax*.85), (double)diffsamp);
    maxsamp = 0;
  }
  if (sign)
  {
    diffsampmax = max((diffsampmax*.85), (double)diffsamp);
    minsamp = 0;
  }
  check = ( diffsamp > max(25.0,diffsampmax*.90) );
  if (sign == lastsign)
  {
    check = false;
  }
  if (check)
  {
    if (timepassed - peaks[0] < 500)
    {
      for ( j=numpeaks-1; j>0; j-- )
      {
        peaks[j] = peaks[j-1];
      }
    }
    else
    {
      for ( j=0; j<numpeaks; j++ )
      {
        peaks[j] = 0;
      }
    }
    peaks[0] = timepassed;
    double diff = peaks[0]-peaks[numpeaks-1];
    double peaktime = diff/(numpeaks-1)*2; //*2 because maxdiff is at +>- and ->+
    frequency = 1/((double)peaktime/(double)SAMPLE_RATE);
    if (peaks[numpeaks-1] <= 0 || frequency < 20) frequency = 0;
    lastsign = sign;
  }
}

static int PaCallback( const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                         unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                         const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                         PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                         void *userData )
{
  const SAMPLE *in = (const SAMPLE*)inputBuffer;
  unsigned int i;
  unsigned int j;
  (void) timeInfo; // Prevent unused variable warnings.
  (void) statusFlags;
  (void) userData;
  SAMPLE samp;

  if( inputBuffer == NULL )
  {
    //nothing happens
  }
  else
  {
    for( i=0; i<framesPerBuffer; i++ )
    {
      timepassed += 1;
      samp = *in++;
      changed = false;
      if (samp > 0)
      {
        if (!sign)
        {
          sign = true;
          changed = true;
        }
        maxsamp = max(maxsamp,samp);
      }
      else
      {
        if (sign)
        {
          sign = false;
          changed = true;
        }
        minsamp = min(minsamp,samp);
      }
      if (changed)
      {
        calculateFreq(sign);
      }
    }
  }
  return paContinue;
}
```

GML:

```
//// Script: pa_init()
globalvar _pa_freq,_pa_start,_pa_end;
var dll_name;
dll_name = "c:\Users\<Username>\Documents\NetBeansProjects\GMDLLtest\dist\Debug\Cygwin_4.x-Windows\libGMDLLtest.dll";

_pa_freq  = external_define(dll_name, "getFreq", dll_cdecl, ty_real, 0);
_pa_start = external_define(dll_name, "PortAudioStart", dll_cdecl, ty_real, 0);
_pa_end   = external_define(dll_name, "PortAudioEnd", dll_cdecl, ty_real, 0);

////--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//// Script: pa_start()
return external_call(_pa_start);

////--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//// Script: pa_end()
return external_call(_pa_end);

////--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//// Script: pa_freq()
return external_call(_pa_freq);
```

P.S: If anything is unclear, please ask, my knowledge of C++ isn't really outstanding.

Comment: It's usually good practice to memset 0 the whole inputParameters structure to ensure you've initialized all fields to zero.

Comment: "I tested this DLL by letting a C++ program call it, and in that case it worked totally as planned." that kind of suggests there is some C++ runtime issue.

Comment: If it were me the next step would be attach the VS debugger to your Game Maker process, put a breakpoint in PortAudioStart() and step through the code to see where it crashes.

Comment: @RossBencina I set everything to 0, didn't solve the problem.

I think it isn't a runtime issue, because like I said, when I call PortAudioStart() from the DLL in a C++ program it still works.

I did put breakpoints in it, I used message boxes. It crashes at Pa_StartStream(), like I told in the info.

Comment: Why oh why would you use a goto there... But besides that, make sure you are not exporting in with the COMPILER, as that is currently broken. What GM version do you use? Also, if you don't think it is a runtime problem shouldn't you be posting the GML?

Comment: @paul23 I don't know if my definition of runtime issue is correct, so it might still be one. In any case, other DLL functions just work, I can still post the GML if you want :) And I used goto cause it was in the PortAudio example itself, so I didn't see why I shouldn't use it. And which compiler do you mean?

Comment: Does the program get into your callback function?  Are you loading the DLL at runtime? Pa_StartSteam starts a thread.  I could see that causing a security issue that windows "fixes" by terminating the application.

Comment: @trukvl as you can see in the code, the callback function isn't exported. So the program isn't messing around with it. And the new thread could be causing it indeed, thanks for this suggestion. :) Though I still wonder how to fix this

Comment: @thecatlover1996 Well first of all, what is your GM version? GM8 or GM:Studio matters a whole lot. In GM studio you can't use the export option "YYC-compiler" when using dlls. But as you indicated the rest works.. So the problem is probably like trukvl said. - Best to attach a debugger to this and run the dll to see what's up.